# Calculate all dates between 2 dates in php?

Tags: php, date, date-arithmetic

I have 2 dates

```
$st_date = '2012-07-20';
$ed_date = '2012-07-27';
```

I want to display all dates from `$st_date` to `$ed_date`
As:

```
2012-07-20
2012-07-21
2012-07-22
2012-07-23
2012-07-24
2012-07-25
2012-07-26
2012-07-27
```

I thought first count difference, run foreach < count, and add $i day to $st_date.
But i don't want loop, it increases code. Any of direct date() which return an array of all-dates.

Comment: Any easy way to return array of All-Dates

Comment: direct dates calculation function

Comment: loop is very last option to do this thing...

Comment: You're going to have a very hard time programming in PHP (or most languages) if you don't like loops!

Comment: yep @vasco, am workin on efficient appointment system, need to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without loop using range() & array_map() :

EDIT: a little mistake, you have to jump 86400, because 1 day = 86400 seconds, so the code should be fine now :)

```
    $st_date = '2012-07-20';
    $ed_date = '2012-07-27';
    $dates = range(strtotime($st_date), strtotime($ed_date),86400);
    $range_of_dates = array_map("toDate", $dates);
    print_r($range_of_dates);
    function toDate($x){return date('Y-m-d', $x);}

?>
```

Comment: ok, so range and array_map = 2 loops =) But looks more elegantly

Comment: @Serjio lol, i don't see any for/while/do statement, but you're right, it's indeed somehow a loop, but with this kind of problem there is no other way :)

Answer (score 4):

try this code :

```
<?php
$st_date = '2012-07-20';
$ed_date = '2012-07-27';

$dateMonthYearArr = array();
$st_dateTS = strtotime($st_date);
$ed_dateTS = strtotime($ed_date);

for ($currentDateTS = $st_dateTS; $currentDateTS <= $ed_dateTS; $currentDateTS += (60 * 60 * 24)) {
// use date() and $currentDateTS to format the dates in between
$currentDateStr = date(“Y-m-d”,$currentDateTS);
$dateMonthYearArr[] = $currentDateStr;
//print $currentDateStr.”<br />”;
}

echo  “<pre>”;
print_r($dateMonthYearArr);
echo “</pre>”;
?>
```

Comment: thatz make sense but loop made me crazy...

Comment: Hey, @Fredy I'll use this at last, if its not done.

Answer (score 3):

Whilst I don't understand your aversion to loops, I do understand hiding code away as much as possible.

To that end, I would extend PHP's [DateTime](http://www.php.net/datetime) object to give the functionality you are after. Something like this:-

```
class MyDateTime extends DateTime
{
    /**
    * Creates an array of date strings of all days between
    * the current date object and $endDate
    * 
    * @param DateTime $endDate
    * @return array of date strings
    */
    public function rangeOfDates(DateTime $endDate)
    {
        $result = array();
        $interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
        //Add a day as iterating over the DatePeriod
        //misses the last day for some strange reason
        //See here http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateperiod.php#102629
        $endDate->add($interval); 
        $period = new DatePeriod($this, $interval, $endDate);
        foreach($period as $day){
            $result[] = $day->format('Y-m-j');
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Then when you want to use it, you can do this:-

```
$st_date = new MyDateTime("2012-07-20");
$en_date = new DateTime("2012-07-27");
$dates = $st_date->rangeOfDates($en_date);
var_dump($dates);
```

Will give the following output:-

```
array
  0 => string '2012-07-20' (length=10)
  1 => string '2012-07-21' (length=10)
  2 => string '2012-07-22' (length=10)
  3 => string '2012-07-23' (length=10)
  4 => string '2012-07-24' (length=10)
  5 => string '2012-07-25' (length=10)
  6 => string '2012-07-26' (length=10)
  7 => string '2012-07-27' (length=10)
```

Although, unfortunately, you will probably need a loop to iterate over that array :)

Obviously, this solution uses loops to achieve its goal, but they are encapsulated in a nice re-usable piece of code.

See the PHP manual on [DateTime](http://www.php.net/datetime), [DateInterval](http://www.php.net/dateinterval) and [DatePeriod](http://www.php.net/dateperiod) for more information. There are lots of tips in the comments to those pages.

Comment: Good catch on adding a date to the last date.

Answer (score 2):

```
$start = strtotime('2009-02-01'); 
$end = strtotime('2009-03-10'); 
$range = array();

$date = strtotime("-1 day", $start);  
while($date < $end)  { 
   $date = strtotime("+1 day", $date);
   $range[] = date('Y-m-d', $date);
}
```

Comment: loop... 
Any easy way to return array of All-Dates by

direct dates calculation function...(8-lines)

Comment: You also can create your own function/method. Can you explain why you need this range?

Answer (score 1):

```
$st_date = '2012-07-20';
$ed_date = '2012-07-27';

for($i=$st_date;$i<=$ed_date;$i++)echo $i."<br />";
```

Comment: Fine for starters, but need to put more code as months change in both start & end date..

Answer (score 0):

Little late to the party, but was tackling this issue earlier and did it with the following, which is cleaner than other examples here, so adding it as an option for people;

```
function dateRange($from, $to)
{
    return array_map(function($arg) {
         return date('Y-m-d', $arg);
    }, range(strtotime($from), strtotime($to), 86400));
}
```

Usage:

```
$dates = dateRange('2017-01-01', '2017-01-08');
```

Returns:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2017-01-01
    [1] => 2017-01-02
    [2] => 2017-01-03
    [3] => 2017-01-04
    [4] => 2017-01-05
    [5] => 2017-01-06
    [6] => 2017-01-07
    [7] => 2017-01-08
)
```