# Display dates from two fields

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, date

I have a table with two columns `startdate` and `enddate` (of type `DATETIME`). When I pass two parameters that is start and end date, I need to display all the dates between the two dates from two columns.

i.e.. I have this table:

```
 startdate  enddate
 ---------------------
 6/1/2012   6/7/2012
 6/5/2012   6/9/2012
 6/10/2012  6/15/2012
```

When I pass two dates like `6/3/2012` and `6/20/2012`, I want to display this result set:

```
  6/5/2012
  6/7/2012
  6/9/2012
  6/10/2012
  6/15/2012
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What datatype are `startdate` and `enddate` ?? And which **version** of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: the data type is datetime and i am using sqlserver 2008

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculate all dates between 2 dates in php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11556354/calculate-all-dates-between-2-dates-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UNION` all dates in a `SubQuery`. Try,

```
SELECT allDates
FROM
(
    SELECT startdate as allDates
    FROM table
    UNION
    SELECT endDate as allDates
    FROM table
) a
WHERE allDates BETWEEN '6/3/2012' AND '6/20/2012'
```

Answer (score 0):

MySql sample syntax :

```
CREATE TABLE TEST(STARTDATE DATE,ENDDATE DATE);

INSERT INTO TEST VALUES (NOW(), NOW());
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES ('2012-08-19', '2012-08-15');
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES ('2012-08-17', '2012-08-10');
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES ('2012-08-23', '2012-08-21');

SELECT STARTDATE FROM TEST WHERE STARTDATE BETWEEN '2012-08-15' AND '2012-08-23' 
UNION SELECT ENDDATE FROM TEST WHERE ENDDATE BETWEEN '2012-08-15' AND '2012-08-23' 
ORDER BY STARTDATE;
```